# Tango with Django tutorial : Forms

Tags: python, django, macos, django-1.6

I am doing the exercises in chapter [7](http://www.tangowithdjango.com/book/chapters/forms.html#exercises) and I have to create an add page link on every category page that would take the users to a new page on which they can enter name and url to add to certain category if the category in question is not existing they would be redirected to the add category page.

so the steps are:

1.Create a new view (the tut gives us this one ready)

```
def add_page(request, category_name_url):
    context = RequestContext(request)
    category_name = category_name_url.replace('_',' ')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PageForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            page = form.save(commit = False)

            try:
                cat = Category.objects.get(name = category_name)
                page.category = cat
            except Category.DoesNotExist:
                return render_to_response('blog/add_category.html', {} , context)

            page.views = 0
            page.save()

            return category(request, category_name_url)
        else:
            print form.errors

   else:
        form = PageForm()

    return render_to_response('blog/add_page.html', {'category_name_url': category_name_url, 'category_name': category_name, 'form': form}, context)
```

2.create a new template

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title> Drib </title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>Add Page</h1>

        <form id = 'page_form' method = 'post' action = '/blog/add_page/'>
            {% csrf_token %}
            {%for hidden in forms.hidden_fields%}
                {{hidden}}
            {%for field in forms.visible_fields%}
                {{field}}
                {{field.errors}}
                {{field.help_text}}
            <input type = 'submit' name='Submit' value = "Add Page" />
        </form>
    </body>


</html>
```

3.URL Mapping

```
url(r'^category/(?P<category_name_url>\w+)/add_page/$', views.add_page , name = 'add_page')
```

4.Create a link from the category page (I am just going to post the link because there is no point to post the whole file...

```
<a href="/blog/category/{{category_name_url}}/add_page/"> Add Page</a>
```

Hints from the tut are :

-Update the category() view to pass category_name_url by inserting it to the view’s context_dict dictionary - DONE

- Update the category.html with a link to /rango/category//add_page/. Ensure that the link only appears when the requested category exists - with or without pages. - I believe i did that in step 4 (not 100 % sure though)

-Update rango/urls.py with a URL mapping to handle the above link.(Step 3 i believe)

My question is why after clicking on the Add Page i get

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/category/Python/blog/category/Python/add_page/
```

instead of

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/category/Python/add_page/
```

Comment: Does adding leading slash to `<a href="/blog/category/{{category_name_url}}/add_page/"> Add Page</a>` help?

Comment: Have you restarted the server to see the changes to take effect?

Comment: I take that back ... It did work , its just that i added one more symbol by mistake ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because

```
<a href="blog/category/{{category_name_url}}/add_page/"> Add Page</a>
```

is a relative link. Meaning that the href is appended to your current path.

To make it an absolute path just prepend a / which gives you the following

```
<a href="/blog/category/{{category_name_url}}/add_page/"> Add Page</a>
         ^ Here's the leading slash
```

Comment: Do you have any idea now that i get the add page and I enter the details why it doesn't actually add the page? I looked at how the tut added the add category and followed the same logic, but it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

To actually add the page, you can change the `action` attribute of the `form` element from

```
/blog/add_page/
```

to

```
/blog/category/{{ category_name_url }}/add_page/
```

Comment: This should probably be the accepted answer since the actual post won't go through unless the URL is matched in urls.py